# How can I set an object in a parent class and use it in child classes?

Tags: php, oop, inheritance

Here's some working code:

```
class A {
    public $Foo;

    public function GetFoo() {
        $this->Foo = 'Bar';
    }
}

class B extends A {
    function __construct() {
        $this->GetFoo();
        echo $this->Foo;
    }
}

$b = new B(); // Outputs "Bar"
```

Is there any way I can make this "prettier" (i.e. without the A::GetFoo() method)? I would've thought that wrapping the population of the $this->Foo inside a A::__construct() would work, but it doesn't.

Just to wrap it up, here's what I want: class A instantiates my DB object and that object is usable for every child class of A.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you're overriding the parent's constructor without calling in from `B`?

```
class A {

    protected $Foo = null;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->Foo = 'Bar';
    }

}

class B extends A {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        echo $this->Foo;
    }

}
```

Comment: Apparently I am. I don't see why that would be the case, since both classes are instantiated with their own objects. I guess I'll have to call the parent contructor in every child constructor then

Comment: @John Yes, indeed. Redefining a method in a child class completely hides the parent method.

Answer (score 1):

From the [PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php):

> "Class properties must be defined as
>   public, private, or protected. If
>   declared using var without an explicit
>   visibility keyword, the property will
>   be defined **as public**."

So, your class `B` can see `$this->Foo`.  You don't have to call `GetFoo()` first.  You must, however, call the parent constructor first if you need to reference `$this->Foo` inside of your constructor for class `B`.